# New to python: porting over an ODE model

Tags: python, matlab, ode

I am trying to port my MATLAB code over to python, but I ran into some issues with indexing.  The code that I pasted below is an ode model that I plan to solve using scipy.integrate.odeint.

The first problem that I ran into is an indexing problem with the code `z[i-np.arange(0,(i-1))` (The equivalent in MATLAB is `z(i-[1:(i-1)])` )

An attempt at a python function for the ode model:

```
def myModel(z,t,k,R,R2,N):

k1=k[0]
k2=k[1]
k3=k[2]

V=1/1.5*(75*z[0]+np.dot((75+57*np.arange(1,np.size(z)-2)),z[1:-2])+114*z[-2])+18*z[-1]

dzdt=np.zeros(N+2)

dzdt[0]=( 1/V*(-2*k1*z[0]*sum(z[0:-2])              
+2*k2*z[-1]*sum(z[1:-2])) ) 

dzdt[1]=( 1/V*(-2*k1*z[1]*sum(z[0:-2])          
+k1*z[0]*z[0]                               
-k2*z[1]*z[-1]                      
-k3*z[1]*V                                      
+2*k2*z[-1]*sum(z[2:-2])              
+k2*z[-2]*z[-1]) )

for i in range(2,len(z)-3):
    dzdt[i]=( 1/V*(-2*k1*z[i]*sum(z[0:-2])          
    +k1*np.dot(z[0:i],z[-(len(z)-i+1)::-1])     
    -k2*z[i]*z[-1]*i                        
    +2*k2*z[-1]*sum(z[i+1:-2])) ) 

dzdt[-3]=( 1/V*(            
+k1*np.dot(z[0:i],z[-(len(z)-i+1)::-1])
-k2*z[i]*z[-1]*i) )

dzdt[-2]=1/V*(k3*z[1]*V-k2*z[-1]*z[-2])
dzdt[-1]=1/V*(k1*sum(z[0:-2])**2-k2*z[-1]*np.dot(np.arange(0,len(z)-2),z[0:-2])+k3*z[1]*V-k2*z[-1]*z[-2]-V*(R*z[-1]/(sum(z))-R2))


return dzdt
```

And the original MATLAB function for the ode model:

```
function dzdt=ode(t,z,k,R,R2)


k1=k(1);
k2=k(2);
k3=k(3);


V=1/1.5*(75*z(1)+(75+57*[1:length(z)-3])*z(2:end-2)+114*z(end-1))+18*z(end);

dzdt=zeros(size(z));

dzdt(1)=1/V*(-2*k1*z(1)*sum(z(1:end-2)) ...             
    +2*k2*z(end)*sum(z(2:end-2)));                  

dzdt(2)=1/V*(-2*k1*z(2)*sum(z(1:end-2)) ...         
    +k1*z(1)*z(1) ...       
    -k2*z(2)*z(end) ...                     
    -k3*z(2)*V ...                                      
    +2*k2*z(end)*sum(z(3:end-2)) ...         
    +k2*z(end-1)*z(end));

for i=3:length(z)-3
    dzdt(i)=1/V*(-2*k1*z(i)*sum(z(1:end-2)) ...         
        +k1*z(1:i-1)'*z(i-[1:(i-1)]) ...        
        -k2*z(i)*z(end)*(i-1) ...                       
        +2*k2*z(end)*sum(z(i+1:end-2)));                       
end

dzdt(end-2)=1/V*( ...           
    +k1*z(1:i-1)'*z(i-[1:(i-1)]) ...        
    -k2*z(i)*z(end)*(i-1) ...                       
    );                          
dzdt(end-1)=1/V*(k3*z(2)*V-k2*z(end)*z(end-1));
dzdt(end)=1/V*(k1*sum(z(1:end-2))^2-k2*z(end)*[0:length(z)-3]*z(1:end-2)+k3*z(2)*V-k2*z(end)*z(end-1)-V*(R*z(end)/(sum(z))-R2));

end
```

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: First thing: Indexing in Matlab starts at **1**, in Python at **0**.

Comment: Damn this code is really unreadable. Is your space bar broken ? Really, make yourself (and the ones reading your code) a favour : use spaces in your code !

Comment: Is your comment in English?  I don't understand what you are saying Dici, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give you two hints:

- In Python, you can't multiply vectors just as in matlab. If V is a array/list, `V'*V` returns the element-wise product in matlab. In Python (numpy) you can use [numpy.dot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to calculate the dot product of two vectors.
- You can use the following format to slice a vector in numpy: v[start:stop:step]. See [the documentation about slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). For example `v[::-1]` gives you the reverse vector.

To illustrate it all:

```
import numpy
a=numpy.array([1,2,3])
b=numpy.array([4,5,6])
a*b              # returns array([ 4, 10, 18])
numpy.dot(a,b)   # returns 32
sum(a*b)         # returns 32
```

Combine the above hints and you don't need `arange` in that line anymore.

As a final note: the community gladly helps you with your problems, but we are **not** a free coding service. Try to show what you have tried and give a minimal showcase of your problem instead of giving us lots of lines. This will result in less downvotes and more answers.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments agtoever.  I am learning!  I still feel so confused about basic differences between the two languages, like indexing, but I am starting to get it.  I apologize for the huge dump of code, but I felt like it was necessary to include lots of examples so that I could get help on places where I am screwing things up.  I tried to update the code based on your suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: The original question was answered by agtoever.  I have updated my original post with a new code that appears to be operating correctly.  This post can be closed.  Thanks

Comment: You can close the post (and give me some reputation) by accepting my answer (green checkmark). I'm glad I could help you.